# Deployment ASP.NET MVC2 with EF v2.0 target framework 3.5 without sp1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment

I have develop a web application using MVC3+EF4.1 but for urgent reason, I have to downgrade the project and target framework 3.5( I think i have use mvc2 + EF v2.0).
I have successfully deployed the site fine in host with .net3.5 sp1 and iis6 with bin deployment. But I have a problem on my customer's host. They didn't update to .net3.5 sp1.

Are there a way to deploy mvc2+EFv2 web application on .net3.5 without sp1?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is part of .NET framework since .NET 3.5 SP1. Without SP1 you have no EF support at all. If your customer is not willing to install SP1 you must completely rewrite your data access to another technology.

.NET 3.5 SP1 contains EFv1 which is mostly incompatible with EFv4.1. If you have developed application with EFv4.1 (POCOs, DbContext API, code-first, etc.) you have no downgrade option. You must mostly reimplement your data access logic with EFv1 and `EntityObject` based entities.